# ^[[3~ try again error in kde konsole

Tags: kde, konsole, kde-neon

I am trying to enter in admin by `sudo su`. But after entering sudo password and pressing enter terminal automatically printing some character and showing try again.

```
^[[3~floki@aspire:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for floki: 
^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for floki: 
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
floki@aspire:~$ ~~~~~~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3
```

Comment: `^[[3~` is the *Delete* key. Probably you have a very wrong `TERM` setting. Note you have the first DELETE before you press sudo. Could you tell us which TERM do you have in environment, and which terminal emulation you set in Konsole settings?

Comment: I am using default bash Konsole which comes with kde neon on my laptop. And also my screen flickers in startup and prints some logs

Comment: I mean: do `echo $TERM` and give us the result. That is the expected emulation (bash do nothing with terminal emulation, it just uses what it get). And konsole has settings: check which terminal emulator is expecting.

Comment: After running the command it's showing `xterm-256color`

Comment: In Konsole environment it is expecting xterm-256color